# Disabling PID output when running command ended with `&`

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I read a solution about running 2 commands at the same time from command line by spawning another process. Say I want to run `commandA` and `commandB` then what I have to write in script is:

```
commandA &
commandB
```

But the problem is, when I run the script, it gives me output in terminal some number (probably PID I think, because if I call `kill <that_number>` it stopped the commandA process) like this:

```
[ 1 ] 2592
# after some time program running
[ 1 ] + 2592 done
```

My question is:

1. What is it that number exactly?
2. How do I disable that output number? Tried to redirect stdout and stderr to dev null doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097761/is-there-a-way-to-make-bash-job-control-quiet

Comment: @tk421 whoaa thanks so much, sorry that I asked quest that have already been asked. I cannot find it via google cause google seems cant read & as syntax...

Comment: No worries, most times search won't give the right answer unless you know the right terminology.  For future reference it's called bash job control.